# Show Users score after losing life in game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have problem with showing score. I'm making mobile game in which I need display my score after loosing "life". I have already displayed score while playing game. But I want that score displayed after losing life. How can I do it?

This is part of my script attached on my project (to ball component). I have a ball which pickup collectable objects " coins ". After loosing life, how can I show result of my countText?

```
public Text countText;


//Usethisfor initialization
void Start () 
{ 
     count = 0;
     countText.text = count.ToString ();


}

//Updateiscalledonceper frame
void Update ()
{

}


void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{


     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("coins")){
     other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
     count += 1;
     countText.text = count.ToString ();
}
```

Thanks,

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I think there are lot of ways to solve this problem. Try my solution:

1. Create "You are dead" screen in UI gameobject.
2. Attach Script with public method `PointsEarned(int points)` (implementation is obvious - setting private int field and/or modify Text element - depends on your requirements)
3. Modify script from question like this:

(Code incomplete)

```
 MyScript screenController;    

 //Usethisfor initialization
 void Start () 
 { 
     count = 0;
     countText.text = count.ToString ();

     screenController = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<MyScript>();
}
```

4. Then, when you find out that player is dead, simply call `screenController.PointsEarned(count);`

Depending how you want your death screen behave, you might need to use `SetActive` on gameobjects like death screen or any other.